# Wordpress 4.2.1 pre_get_comments this doesn't work after update

Tags: wordpress

I have this code working all time but, after updating to Wordpress 4.2.1, this doesn't work.

```
// return just the missing replies in the comment table
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', array( $this, 'return_missing_list' ) );
public function return_missing_list( $comments = array() ) {

    // bail on anything not admin
    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    // only run this on the comments table
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if( 'edit-comments' !== $current_screen->base )
        return;

    // check for query param
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['missing_reply'] ) )
        return;

    // now run action to show missing
    $comments->query_vars['meta_key']   = '_cnrt_missing';
    $comments->query_vars['meta_value'] = '1';
    $comments->query_vars['date_query'] = array(
                'after' => '10 months ago'
            );

    // Because at this point, the meta query has already been parsed,
    // we need to re-parse it to incorporate our changes
    $comments->meta_query->parse_query_vars( $comments->query_vars );
} // end missing_reply_list
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to elaborate on "*this doesn't work*" please?

Comment: Of course! I did it. Sorry! :)